# Offline WebBrowsing

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, delphi, twebbrowser

I have application that I am slowly migrating to a web deploy. What I am essentially doing is recreating every form in the app into vue JS web pages. Then I have a generic form in the app that displays a web browser that doesn't look like a web browser. This lets my app look nearly identical (if not better with the power of css) to how it did before.

This is all working great but now I am beginning to look at a offline mode. For now everything is just falling back to the old code but my goal is to deprecate the fallback version and only apply new updates to the web forms.

In my attempts to accomplish this I created a http proxy server to run inside of my application in a thread. If the app is set to use the web forms then I proxy through localhost to the server which will do one of two things.

1.) If the app hasn't visited the site in question before then it will do a reach out to the actual page and store the html.

2.) If the app has visited the site before it will serve up the previous html.

My problem is I am clearly not caching enough by just storing the html. My pages I load have no images and the formatting looks way off. Here is an example visiting google:

[image]

You can see it didn't cache the images and the css formatting didn't seem to stick.

So my question is what things do I need to do on the HTML side to assure that all the information needed to run the app in offline mode is available? And what would my application need to store from the web page to assure it has all the info it needs? Right now I am just storing html but I assume I would need to pull down scripts and images as well?

Comment: Why not always access thru the proxy you wrote and cache everything passing? In online mode, you make like the cache always miss and for offline mode, you never reach the remote server. Of course this offline mode will never show anything the user has not already visited in online. And you have to solve the issue of cache being too old each time the remote server is updated.

Comment: I am doing this! I have a proxy mode and the intent is that will always be flagged on. Then the reach out only happens if they don't have a local copy stored. This is what I am doing but the issue is with the pages that I am caching not properly displaying things like images because I am only pulling down the raw html through a GET call to the page they are trying to hit.

Comment: I just don't know what extra I need to store to show the page properly. You can see in the picture it isn't rendering the css or the veterans day image. I thought this would be mostly imbedded in the raw html but apparently not!

Comment: I guess to add to this more, the component I am using to browse has built in caching but it doesn't have a way to store across multiple runs of the application. Once the app dies, the cache dies. So I am having to manually cache. And my manual cache of just the raw html apparently is not sufficent.

Comment: If your proxy act like a real proxy, then it receive ALL the request and you may then cache everything.

Comment: Well it also depends on how the html pages are referring to the images and css files. When the raw html is using absolute links (including http(s):// ) then the browser itself won’t be trying to load them from your local (proxy) server.

Comment: Yeah Hoek I think this is my issue. My vue pages load in a bunch of other pages and css pages. I'm currently attempting to pull down all the needed files locally and changing the base html to point to "file://" locations instead. This is super hacky but maybe what I need to do!